# Expanding header for long project titles in Redmine's default theme

Tags: css, redmine

I'm trying to adjust the standard Redmine theme to solve a problem with wrapping of long project title breadcrumbs in the page header. The problem makes heavily nested project titles show up like this:

[image: Redmine subprojects with long titles]

I've found a couple of [tickets](http://www.redmine.org/issues/7848) and [board posts](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/22454?r=22459) about similar issues, but nobody with a proper resolution for it.

What I'm trying to do is keep `#main-menu` at the bottom of `#header`, and to have `#header` expand when the text wraps. Just making `#header` larger than the initial fixed `height` works, but looks a bit odd for short titles. Is there a nice way of doing this without completely restyling the header? (that's my fallback idea). Ideally I'd also like to do it without just removing items from the list.

I think the layout on [the official Redmine site](http://www.redmine.org) uses the same CSS and HTML for reference, but the relevant bits are:

#### HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="quick-search"></div>
    <h1>
      <a href="" class="root">Test Project</a> » … » 
      <a class="ancestor">Really long project title 2</a> » 
      <a class="ancestor">Really long project title 3</a> » 
      Really project title 4
    </h1>
    <div id="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#header {
  height: 5.3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 8px 0px 6px;
  position: relative;
}

#main-menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 6px;
  margin-right: -500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome.  Not tested elsewhere.

Change the `divs` in the `header div` to floats as follows

```
#quick-search {
float: right;
margin-top: 0.8em;
width: 25%;
text-align: right; 
} 

#header h1 {
margin-top: 0.3em;
margin-left: 0px;
float: left;
width: 75%;
}

#main-menu {
float: left;
clear: both;
left: 6px;
}
```

You may need to fiddle with the widths.

Also add a `br` after the `main menu div` but before the `</div>` for the `header`

```
 <br style="clear:both">
```

Remove the `height` on the `#header div`